# How to fix this cant view the login page in Codeigniter 3 running in linux

Tags: linux, codeigniter-3

When viewing my project in codeigniter 3 stuck at configuration index.php instead redirect me in views page "login".

Codeigniter 3.1.10 running in Apache 2 and php5.6 on Ubuntu.

I need your help, thanks..

[image: Result when viewing my project]

Comment: Is your "DocumentRoot" configured correctly? in your httpd.conf file. Chances are it will be under something like /etc/apache2/conf/httpd.conf

Answer (score 0):

Probably you don't have PHP installed.

```
sudo apt-get install php libapache2-mod-php
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: thanks but already installed it still didnt work, well  in Windows using xamp it runs fine... I dont know what I missed configuration.